# Demi ou semi, quelle différence ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, nombres, préfixes

J'ai récemment rencontré l'expression « demi-marathon » alors que je suis plutôt habitué à voir « semi-marathon ».

Quand on va chez le boulanger on demande une « demi-baguette ». Une « semi-baguette » sonne « faux ».

Les deux mots ont l'air de dire la même chose. Il y a-t-il une règle pour choisir entre « demi » ou « semi », ou le choix est-il dicté suivant l'habitude ?

Comment: J'aurais tendance à dire "demi" pour un objet qu'on coupe en deux, et "semi" pour quelque chose de plus abstrait (un marathon n'est pas un objet)... mais sans aucune conviction...

Comment: Je suis très curieux de savoir où tu as rencontré  « demi-marathon ».  Entendu dire par un Québécois ? Et tu es francophone européen ?

Comment: @Laure exactement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La différence réside non pas dans la course - qui couvre dans les deux cas une distance de  21,097 kilomètres, soit la moitié d'un marathon - mais dans le lieu où elle se déroule.

En France (et dans le reste de l'Europe francophone) on parle de semi-marathon, alors qu'[au Québec on parle de demi-marathon](http://www.couriraquebec.com/marathondesdeuxrives/marathon_demi-marathon_10km/).

Je ne résiste pas à l'envie de donner une explication qui reflète bien l'humour de nos amis québécois que j'ai bien sûr trouvée sur un [site de courses d’endurance du Québec](http://www.iskio.ca/2012/10/semi-ou-demi/):

> *En anglais, les mots commençant par semi- sont plus nombreux (951 semi- words, 215 hemi- and 172 demi-). So semi- is by far the most common.*
>
> *Le préfixe ‘demi’ semble-t-il a été formé au temps Norman (lexical inventory or the period of French lingua franca – when it was the working language), et se retrouve souvent associé aux armoiries, costumes, etc…*
>
> *De son côté, semi est utilisé pour connecter des mots techniques de disciplines variées: science, arts, maths, musique.*
>
> *Nos amis Français ayant une tendance à utiliser les termes anglais (runner, challenge, trail, newletter, pasta party, etc…), il faut donc peut-être considérer semi-marathon comme un autre anglicisme.*
>
> *Dans les faits, le plus probable est qu’il s’agit là d’un héritage inter-européen prenant sa source dans l’origine même des compétitions d’athlétisme.*

L'auteur de ces lignes, pas plus que moi n'a pas pu trouvé d'historique plus précis.

Sinon nous pouvons trouver la différence entre les préfixes semi- et demi- sur le site de  [La banque de données terminologiques et linguistiques du gouvernement du Canada](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_s&page=9VmCtM9AAAAA.html).

**Différence entre semi et demi/mi**

> En règle générale, le préfixe semi– est synonyme de demi– et de mi–. Ces préfixes signifient « à demi », « à moitié », « partiellement » ou « imparfaitement ». Ils sont invariables et toujours suivis d’un trait d’union :
>
> - des matières semi-transparentes
> - des matières demi-transparentes
>
> Emprunté au latin, le préfixe semi– entre dans la composition de nombreux mots français. Il s’emploie surtout dans la langue juridique, technique et scientifique, tandis que le préfixe demi– appartient à la langue courante.
>
> Le sens de semi– se rapproche parfois du verbe sembler, tandis que demi– peut prendre un sens très arithmétique de « division par deux » (demi-douzaine). Ainsi, semi-retraite et demi-retraite n’ont pas le même sens dans les phrases suivantes :
>
> - être à la semi-retraite (= régime de travail réduit)
> - toucher une demi-retraite (= recevoir 50 % de la rente de la retraite)

Pour ce qui est de la « demi-baguette » tout comme « demi-heure» ou « demi-douzaine » etc. on ne pourrait pas parler de « semi- » parce que le mot dans ce cas a le

> sens arithmétique de « division par deux ».

Dans « semi-marathon » on peut considérer que c'est la distance parcourue qui est coupée en deux de façon arithmétique, le marathon restant un concept et il est « semi- »  parce qu'il est imparfait par rapport à une certaine norme.

Answer (score 3):

If I go by all the "demi/semi" expressions that I have come across so far, I'd say that "demi" means "à moitié" and "semi" means "partiellement / moins que la moitié".

Considering that:

> "faire un demi-tour" means "do a 180 degree turn"

Whereas:

> "semi-automatique" means "automatique en partie"